# Identify a scraper in realtime - PHP - tail the access file in Memory

Tags: php, linux, memory, nginx

### Background

Legitimate spiders are great.  Its part of the web, I'm happy for them to access my site.

None authorised spiders which scrape my site are bad and I want rid of them.

I have a PHP application that monitors my website access files.  Every time a user with a suspect UserAgent hits the site the system check the access log for entries from the same IP address and makes a judgement about its behaviour.  If its not a human, and I have not authorised it then it gets logged and I may (or may not) take action such as blocking etc.

The way it works is that every time a page loads this process of checking the access file happens.  I only check suspect UserAgent's so the number of checks is kept to a minimum.

### Question

What I want to do is check every single visit that hits the site (i.e. check the last 50 lines of the access file to see if any relate to that visits IP).  But that means every child process my web server handles will want to open the one single access log file.  This sounds like a resource and I/O blocking nightmare.

Is there a way I can 'tail' the access.log file into some sort of central memory that all the web processes have access to at the same time (or very quickly at least).  Perhaps loading it into Memcache or similar.  But how would I do that in realtime? So the last 500 lines of the access.log file loads into memory continuously (but only 500 expunging as it goes, not an ever increasing number).

So in simple terms: is there a php or linux or 'other' way of buffering an ever increasing file (i.e. nginx log file) into memory so that other processes can access the information concurrently (or at least quicker than all reading the file off the hard drive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to know that a well-written service will always be able to mimic a browser's behaviour, unless you do some very weird stuff that will influence the user experience of legitimate visitors.

However, there are a few measures to deal even with sophisticated scrapers:

## 0. Forget about …

… referrer and UA strings. Those are easy to forge, and some legitimate users don't have a common one. You will get lots of false positives/negatives and not gain much.

## 1. Throttle

Web servers like Apache or nginx have core or addon features to throttle the request rate for certain requests. For example, you could allow the downloading of one *.html page per two seconds, but not limit assets like JS/CSS. (Keep in mind that you should also notify legitimate bots via robots.txt of the delays).

## 2. Fail2ban

Fail2ban does something similar to what you want to do: it scans log files for malicious requests and blocks them. It works great against malware bots, it should be possible to configure it to deal with scrapers (at least the less clever ones).

--

These are the ones that specifically answer your question, but there are a couple more, which you could consider:

## 3. Modify contents

This is actually a real fun one: From time to time, we make minor (automated) modifications of the HTML pages and of the JSON feeds, which force the scrapers to adapt their parsers. The fun part is when we see outdated data on their websites for a couple of days until they catch up. Then we modify it again.

## 4. Restrict: Captchas and Logins

Apart from the throttling on the web server level, we count the requests per IP address per hour. If it's more than a certain number (which should be enough for a legitimate user), each request to the API requires solving a captcha.

Other APIs require authentication, so they won't even get into those areas.

## 5. Abuse nofifications

If get regular visits from a certain IP address or subnet, you can do a WHOIS lookup for the network service from which they are running their bots. Usually, they have Abuse contacts, and usually those contacts are very eager to hear about policy violations. Because the last thing they want is to get on blacklists (which we will submit them to, if they don't cooperate).

Also, if you see advertising on the scraper's website, you should notify the advertising networks of the fact that they're being used in the context of stolen material.

## 6. IP bans

Quite obviously you can block a single IP address. What we do is even blocking entire data centers like those of AWS, Azure, etc. There are lists of IP ranges available on the web for all of those services.

Of course, if there are partner services legitimately accessing your site from a data-center, you must whitelist them.

By the way, we don't do this in the web server but on the firewall level (IPtables).

## 7. Legal measures

If you think that the scraper might be afraid of legal actions from your side, you should not hesitate to contact them and make clear that they infringe on your copyright and terms of usage, and they may become subject to legal actions.

## 8. Conclusion

After all, fighting scrapers is a “fight against windmills”, and it may take a lot of effort. You will not be able to prevent all of it, but you should concentrate on the ones that harm you, e.g. by wasting your ressources or making money that would belong to you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Rather than banning/blocking the scrapers I am interested in identifying the IP addresses related to the scraper and making that information available to my application.  Therefore your point **4. Restrict: Captchas and Logins** interests me.  You say "we count the requests per IP address per hour".  What do you use to monitor the requests?  I can do the same thing using zcat/awk/grep on my log files but thats after the fact.  I want to know immediately... say after the 10th url that has been accessed too quickly to be a human.

Comment: We are indeed using a memcache-based approach. We store an array in memcache, where the IP address is the key and the value is another array with the last timestamps. If a certain number is exceeded, the IP address is **permanently** blocked. But it is to say that we do this only for special parts of the API, and it is quite “expensive”. Also, it is a bit dangerous, because it is theoretically prone to (D)DoS attacks. Therefore, we have a “kill switch” to deactivate this feature in case the memcache array gets to big or we see huge amounts of concurrent requests.